# how to force the text to be written in a new page

Tags: two-column

i want to split the page into two columns. to that, i referred to some posts and i found the below posted code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{enumerate}
 \item First item \\
    This is the second line in item and this may extend to third if long
\item second item\ldots
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}%
\hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{\textwidth}}
This is second part \\
$f(x) = 2x + 3y$ This line may go all along the end and wrap afterwards to 
the next as seen here\\
This is a forced next line by ending the previous line 
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}%
\end{document}
```

but the problem i am facing is, the more i addt text to either the right column or the left one, the page gets increases in size but never write in a new page. for an example, if i write more than the page can contain in the 
right or the left section, every thing will be written in the same page and never be written in a new page

how to force the text to be written to a new page

Comment: The issue is that you're wrapping everything in a minipage to do the two columns.  You be better off using a proper multicolumn layout; see for example https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Multiple_columns for a tutorial.

Comment: you need package like [paracol](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/paracol)